# Initial Default Response from AIML

Tags: aiml, program-o

I have faced an issue with AIML conversation, I am using multiple AIML files in chatbot but whenever I start the conversation with the chatbot it is showing “No AIML category found.This is a Default Response" initially, and if I continue the same question again it gives a proper response.

ex:

User: Hi

bot: No AIML category found. This is a Default Response.

User: Hi

bot: Hello

I’ve checked the conversation log of program-o and attached the image
[image]

But here it will respond properly when sending the same message again.

I can't see this in my unknown inputs log in program-o,

And then I got these from my debug log

> “30-04-2018 05:14:48.76763[4][4] - Elapsed time: 0.020 milliseconds
>
> [load_userfunctions.php][Called outside of function][14]
>
> userfunctions include files loaded “

And these lines are written in error log

> 04/30/2018 05:14:41 - PHP ERROR [Notice] -Undefined index: srai_input in >/var/www/html/chatbot/core/aiml/parse_aiml.php on Line 297”

I am facing these issues in my all program-o bots